# What is the meaning of "hospitality maintenance"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, terminology

I saw there's a kind of job called "hospitality maintenance", but I just can't find specific explanation of or concrete description of it. I want to know how I can relate it to certain kind of jobs or industry in my country. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link to where you saw *hospitality maintenance* mentioned? It might mean many different things, context is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hospitality is work in the hotel industry.
Maintenance is work fixing the grounds such as plumbing, mowing grass, changing light bulbs, and cleaning outdoors.

Hospitality maintenance will either be work cleaning inside hotels or work as a groundskeeper for a hotel.

Comment: I suppose it might apply to any of the jobs you've mentioned, but the first one that comes to mind for me is it's a weasely euphemism for *hotel [room cleaning service] **maid***.